# R previous index per group

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to set the previous observation per group to NA, if a certain condition applies.

Assume I have the following datatable:

```
DT = data.table(group=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), v=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), y=c(1,3,6,6,3,1,1,3,6), a=1:9, b=9:1)
```

and I am using the simple condition:

```
DT[y == 6]
```

How can I set the previous rows of `DT[y == 6]` within `DT` to NA, namely the rows with the numbers 2 and 8 of `DT`? That is, how to set the respectively previous rows per group to NA.

Please note: From `DT` we can see that there are 3 rows when y is equal to 6, but for group a (row nr 4) I do not want to set the previous row to `NA`, as the previous row belongs to a different group.

So what I want in different terms is the previous index of certain elements in datatable. Is that possible? Would be also interesting if one can go further back than 1 period. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: what is your desired output? set all columns in previous row to NA?

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the row indices where current y is not 6 and next row is 6, then set the whole row to NA:

```
DT[shift(y, type="lead")==6 & y!=6, 
    (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) NA)]
DT
```

output:

```
   group  v  y  a  b
1:     b  1  1  1  9
2:  <NA> NA NA NA NA
3:     b  1  6  3  7
4:     a  2  6  4  6
5:     a  2  3  5  5
6:     a  1  1  6  4
7:     c  1  1  7  3
8:  <NA> NA NA NA NA
9:     c  2  6  9  1
```

---

As usual, Frank commenting with a more succinct version:

```
DT[shift(y, type="lead")==6 & y!=6, names(DT) := NA]
```

Comment: thanks, very interesting approach to use shift in `i`!

Comment: This also seems to work: `DT[shift(y, type="lead") == 6 & y != 6, names(DT) := NA]`